# TableModelListener changing the values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, event-listener

I am trying the write the code of the number converter tool in 8085 simulator. I created Jtable called "noConTool with  the size 2,8. Then I wrote the listener. However it does not work.

```
 private class hexaListener implements TableModelListener
{
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getColumn() == 0 && e.getFirstRow() == 1)
        {
             Object i = noConTool.getValueAt(1,0);
             String s = i.toString();
             int j = Integer.parseInt(s , 16);
             noConTool.setValueAt(Integer.toString(j), 1, 1);

        }

        else if(e.getColumn() == 1 && e.getFirstRow() == 1)
        {
            Object  k = noConTool.getValueAt(1,1);
            String p = k.toString();
            int u = Integer.parseInt(p);
            noConTool.setValueAt(Integer.toString(u), 1, 0);

        }
        else
            System.out.println("Thank you");



}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying *doesn't work*?

Comment: Can you explain your problem more ?

Comment: @Maroun when ı ran my program it says gives erros like at javax swing table abstract table model.fireTableChanged Abstract Tablemodel.java : 256 . What am I supposed to do ?

Comment: @VKSingla in that tool the cells in Jtable are changing according to entered values. I wrote the code for it when ı wrote my code for one cell it works but for two cells it does not work.

Comment: See also [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).